# Multiple selects for Today,Last Week, Last Month, This Week

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok, so I am trying to create a TSQL result set, for each message type in my table for Today, Last Week, Last Month and This Week. The different message types are 101,103,202.

the following sql produces the output i need, but i can't figure out how to filter the results based upon the three message types.

```
Select distinct
  ( Select Count(*) from MsgDateDetail
      Where convert(date,MsgDate,103) = Convert(date,GETDATE())
And SenderBIC = @senderbic) As Today,
  ( Select Count(*) from MsgDateDetail
      Where MsgDate Between DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, GetDate())-1)-7, GetDate())
      And DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, GetDate()))-7, GetDate())
      And SenderBIC = @senderbic) As LastWeek,
  ( Select Count(*) FROM MsgDateDetail
      Where convert(date,MsgDate,103) = (DATEADD(mm,-1, Convert(date,GETDATE())))
And SenderBIC = @senderbic) AS LastMonth,
  ( Select Count(*) from MsgDateDetail
      Where MsgDate between (DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0,GETDATE()),-1)) AND getDate()
      And SenderBIC = @senderbic) AS ThisWeek
FROM MsgDateDetail h1
```

[image]

***EDIT ***

Post results from Lolo
[image: Results of post from Lolo]

Comment: can you clarify re: message types? What field is it - SenderBIC? Do you want 1 row per message type containing that type's counts?

Comment: Sorry. the field is MsgType. so the table result above includes all message types, i need a row per messages type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    MsgType,

    SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, MsgDate, 103) = 
                  CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Today,

    SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, MsgDate, 103) BETWEEN 
                  DATEADD(DD, -(DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())-1)-7, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DD, 7-(DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()))-7, GETDATE()) 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As LastWeek,

    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEADD(DD, -DATEPART(DD, CONVERT(DATE, MsgDate, 103)) + 1, CONVERT(DATE, MsgDate, 103)) = 
                  DATEADD(MM, -1, DATEADD(DD, -DATEPART(DD, GETDATE()) + 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())))
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As LastMonth,

    SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, MsgDate, 103) BETWEEN 
                  DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,GETDATE()),-1) AND GETDATE() 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As ThisWeek
FROM 
    MsgDateDetail
WHERE
    SenderBIC = @senderbic

GROUP BY
    MsgType
```

To get one row per `MsgType` use group by. I've also modified the way count is evaluated - in my solution there aren't subqueries which should give you speed up. Also you may want to add date filter in where clause.

Comment: @CSharpNewBee I've corrected syntax errors, but there is still some issue with LastMonth counting

Comment: @CSharpNewBee I've also fixed LastMonth count.

Comment: Yeah, your right. So it all works fine, except for the last month results. Back to the drawing board on that one. Unless you can spot the error in my ways?

Comment: @CSharpNewBee I've just fixed it (like 5 mins ago). You were comparing date from last month (for instance 14/10/2013) instead of comparing months. I've changed it by substracting days from date.